# Broken package after update: linux-headers, error broken count >0

Tags: apt, updates

Ubuntu 10.04.

After an update, I get a red warning icon in the system tray, warning about an `error: broken count >0`

Opening Update manager, I see that the broken package is `linux-headers-2.6.32-38 (new install)`

Trying to use the update manager, I get a further error message: `You have 1 broken package on your system! Use the "Broken" filter to locate it.`

and then:

```
E: /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-headers-2.6.32-38_2.6.32-38.83_all.deb: unable to create `/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.32-38/arch/arm/mach-netx/include/mach/vmalloc.h.dpkg-new' (while processing `./usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.32-38/arch/arm/mach-netx/include/mach/vmalloc.h')
```

I tried `apt-get clean` as suggested in another question on this site, and tried reinstalling the package in Synaptic.

One option I have not tried is simply to restart, but I don't dare to in case I can't reboot back into Ubuntu.

I have also tried `apt-get install --fix-broken` and I get the following:

```
The following extra packages will be installed:
  linux-headers-2.6.32-38
The following NEW packages will be installed
  linux-headers-2.6.32-38
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0B/9,937kB of archives.
After this operation, 76.2MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
(Reading database ... 589950 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking linux-headers-2.6.32-38 (from .../linux-headers-2.6.32-38_2.6.32-38.83_all.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-headers-2.6.32-38_2.6.32-38.83_all.deb (--unpack):
unable to create `/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.32-38/arch/arm/mach-nomadik/Makefile.boot.dpkg-new' (while processing `./usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.32-38/arch/arm/mach-nomadik/Makefile.boot'): No space left on device
No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full error
                                                                              dpkg-deb: subprocess paste killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/linux-headers-2.6.32-38_2.6.32-38.83_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Looks like your drive is full and has no free space. Try moving some unwanted files like music, videos, documents and such to another partition. And then try the `sudo apt-get install --fix-broken` . You need to move about *76.2 MB* of stuff to be exact, but might as well move what you can.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! This worked, as you suggested, I cleaned up my system to free some space (I have a separate partition for the file system, so I had to remove old kernels and packages, Ubuntu Tweak helped me do this easily).

Comment: Please make this comment into an answer so I can mark it as solved.

Comment: Cool :) Added the comment as an answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like your drive is full and has no free space. Try moving some unwanted files like music, videos, documents and such to another partition. And then try the `sudo apt-get install --fix-broken` . You need to move about 76.2 MB of stuff to be exact, but might as well move what you can.

After that your system should be back to normal with no broken packages :)