# Error broken count>0

Tags: 11.10, apt, package-management

I am running `Ubuntu 11.10`. I have this error message that shows as a no-entry sign such as [this](http://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/e/b/1/12362679671889420116paulo_tavares_No_Entry.svg.med.png&imgrefurl=http://www.clker.com/clipart-no-entry-sign.html&h=300&w=294&sz=58&tbnid=C0ZjRlbghmq5iM:&tbnh=90&tbnw=88&zoom=1&usg=__C3EhezLXG0jHO9J44RNejKgwntk=&docid=2We-PKRvslJwZM&sa=X&ei=G7YXUa2oK4ro2gXPmYHYDw&ved=0CD4Q9QEwAw&dur=657).

I read the following questions on the forum:

[Broken package after update: linux-headers, error brokencount >0](https://askubuntu.com/q/223143/41821)

[Dependencies not met on 12.04? duplicate](https://askubuntu.com/q/196985/41821)

[Broken package after update: linux-headers, error broken count >0](https://askubuntu.com/q/98752/41821)

However, these point to my drive being full.
I ran `df -i` and got the following output:

```
df -i
Filesystem            Inodes   IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/sda1            30048256  985142 29063114    4% /
udev                 1010270     511 1009759    1% /dev
tmpfs                1012523     445 1012078    1% /run
none                 1012523       1 1012522    1% /run/lock
none                 1012523       8 1012515    1% /run/shm
```

The error message also suggests that I run `sudo apt-get install -f`. I don't know what that does and when I run it, it warns me that it is going to remve about 2 GB worth of stuff!

> ```
> sudo apt-get install -f
> [sudo] password for dnaneet: 
> Reading package lists... Done
> Building dependency tree       
> Reading state information... Done
> Correcting dependencies... Done
> The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
>   libgdl-3-common libaccess-bridge-java python-logilab-astng freetennis-common
>   libntfs10 pylint sensible-mda cdparanoia libanjuta-3-0 python-sphinx
>   python-mako python-pywapi texlive python-pygments libqtscript4-network id3v2
>   python-reportlab libqtscript4-gui mercurial pyflakes libboost-signals1.46.1
>   assaultcube-data texlive-fonts-recommended python-uniconvertor
>   libtag-extras1 libqtscript4-sql python-renderpm libgtkpod1 libid3-3.8.3c2a
>   k3b-data libqtscript4-xml procmail libqjson0 python-dnspython
>   libjs-underscore libaccess-bridge-java-jni tipa libcluttergesture-0.0.2-0
>   indicator-status-provider-emesene amarok-utils python-svn python-docutils
>   libclutter-imcontext-0.1-0 python-rope cheese-common amarok-common
>   texlive-fonts-recommended-doc anjuta-common wine1.2-gecko libmx-1.0-2
>   vorbis-tools python-logilab-common python-markupsafe libgtksourceview2.0-0
>   gtkpod-data libenet1a libqtscript4-uitools liblastfm0 libgsl0ldbl
>   python-roman libloudmouth1-0 python-jinja2 libqtscript4-core python-xmpp
>   libclutter-gtk-1.0-0 libgdl-3-1 libjs-sphinxdoc python-reportlab-accel
>   libgtksourceview2.0-common mercurial-common
> Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
> The following packages will be REMOVED:
>   0ad 0ad-data 0ad-data-common amarok apturl banshee
>   banshee-extension-soundmenu banshee-extension-ubuntuonemusicstore
>   bluez-gstreamer brasero brasero-cdrkit cb2bib cheese dconf-tools emesene
>   empathy evolution-data-server gimp ginn gir1.2-rb-3.0 gir1.2-totem-1.0
>   gir1.2-webkit-3.0 gloobus-preview gnome-codec-install gnome-control-center
>   gnome-media gnome-online-accounts gnome-power-manager gnome-session-fallback
>   gnome-shell gnome-tweak-tool gnome-user-guide gnome-video-effects gnuplot
>   gnuplot-x11 gstreamer0.10-alsa gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg
>   gstreamer0.10-fluendo-mp3 gstreamer0.10-gconf gstreamer0.10-nice
>   gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad-multiverse
>   gstreamer0.10-plugins-base gstreamer0.10-plugins-base-apps
>   gstreamer0.10-plugins-good gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly
>   gstreamer0.10-pulseaudio gstreamer0.10-tools gstreamer0.10-x gtkpod gwibber
>   indicator-datetime indicator-power inkscape k3b kde-runtime kdebase-runtime
>   kdelibs5-plugins kdemultimedia-kio-plugins kile kile-l10n konsole
>   kubuntu-debug-installer libbrasero-media3-1 libcanberra-gtk3-module
>   libcheese-gtk20 libcheese1 libclutter-gst-1.0-0 libdmapsharing-3.0-2
>   libgnome-media-profiles-3.0-0 libgoa-1.0-0 libgstfarsight0.10-0
>   libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0 libgstreamer0.10-0 libk3b6
>   libk3b6-extracodecs libkcddb4 libkdewebkit5 libokularcore1 libplasma3
>   libpurple0 libqtwebkit-dev libqtwebkit4 libreoffice-base-core
>   libreoffice-calc libreoffice-common libreoffice-core libreoffice-draw
>   libreoffice-emailmerge libreoffice-gnome libreoffice-gtk libreoffice-help-de
>   libreoffice-help-en-gb libreoffice-help-en-us libreoffice-help-fr
>   libreoffice-impress libreoffice-l10n-de libreoffice-l10n-en-gb
>   libreoffice-l10n-en-za libreoffice-l10n-fr libreoffice-math
>   libreoffice-style-human libreoffice-writer librhythmbox-core4 libslv2-9
>   libsyncdaemon-1.0-1 libtelepathy-farsight0 libtotem0 libubuntuone-1.0-1
>   libubuntuone1.0-cil libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 libwebkitgtk-3.0-0 libwxgtk2.8-0
>   libyelp0 metacity mythes-de mythes-de-ch mythes-en-au mythes-en-us mythes-fr
>   nautilus-sendto-empathy nautilus-share netflix-desktop notify-osd okular
>   oneconf openoffice.org-common phonon phonon-backend-gstreamer
>   plasma-scriptengine-javascript playonlinux python-farsight python-gst0.10
>   python-lxml python-papyon python-qt4 python-spyderlib
>   python-ubuntuone-client python-ubuntuone-control-panel python-uno
>   python-webkit python-wxgtk2.8 python-wxversion qapt-batch rhythmbox
>   rhythmbox-plugin-cdrecorder rhythmbox-plugins screenlets screenlets-pack-all
>   sessioninstaller shotwell software-center spyder steam:i386
>   telepathy-butterfly telepathy-haze totem totem-mozilla totem-plugins
>   ubuntu-docs ubuntu-sso-client ubuntuone-client ubuntuone-client-gnome
>   ubuntuone-control-panel ubuntuone-control-panel-gtk ubuntuone-couch unity-2d
>   update-notifier wine-browser-installer xul-ext-ubufox yelp zenity
> 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 172 to remove and 11 not upgraded.
> 10 not fully installed or removed.
> After this operation, 2,001 MB disk space will be freed.
> Do you want to continue [Y/n]?
> ```

So what should I do about this?

**Edit: List of recent packages installed**

> ```
> 2013-02-05 07:47:12 status installed man-db 2.6.0.2-2
> 2013-02-05 07:47:13 status installed bamfdaemon 0.2.104-0ubuntu1.1
> 2013-02-05 07:47:14 status installed desktop-file-utils 0.18-0ubuntu9
> 2013-02-05 07:47:14 status installed gnome-menus 3.2.0-0ubuntu2
> 2013-02-05 07:47:25 status installed hicolor-icon-theme 0.12-1ubuntu1
> 2013-02-05 07:47:26 status installed menu 2.1.45ubuntu1
> 2013-02-05 07:47:28 status installed initramfs-tools 0.99ubuntu8
> 2013-02-05 07:51:28 status installed google-chrome-stable 24.0.1312.68-r180326
> 2013-02-05 07:51:28 status installed ubuntu-docs 11.10.6
> 2013-02-05 07:51:28 status installed inkscape 0.48.2-0ubuntu1.1
> 2013-02-05 07:51:29 status installed libavutil-extra-51 4:0.7.6ubuntu0.11.10.3+medibuntu1
> 2013-02-05 07:51:29 status installed libavcodec-extra-53 4:0.7.6ubuntu0.11.10.3+medibuntu1
> 2013-02-05 07:51:29 status installed whois 5.0.11ubuntu3
> 2013-02-05 07:51:30 status installed mendeleydesktop 1.8-stable
> 2013-02-05 07:51:30 status installed chromium-codecs-ffmpeg 24.0.1312.56-0ubuntu0.11.10.1
> 2013-02-05 07:51:30 status installed chromium-browser 24.0.1312.56-0ubuntu0.11.10.1
> 2013-02-05 07:51:31 status installed chromium-browser-l10n 24.0.1312.56-0ubuntu0.11.10.1
> 2013-02-05 07:51:41 status installed menu 2.1.45ubuntu1
> 2013-02-05 07:51:42 status installed libc-bin 2.13-20ubuntu5.3
> 2013-02-05 07:51:42 status installed initramfs-tools 0.99ubuntu8
> 2013-02-09 12:46:24 startup archives install
> 2013-02-09 12:50:39 startup archives install
> 2013-02-09 12:50:47 install steam:i386 <none> 1.0.0.25
> 2013-02-09 12:50:49 status installed bamfdaemon 0.2.104-0ubuntu1.1
> 2013-02-09 12:50:50 status installed desktop-file-utils 0.18-0ubuntu9
> 2013-02-09 12:50:50 status installed gnome-menus 3.2.0-0ubuntu2
> 2013-02-09 12:51:04 status installed hicolor-icon-theme 0.12-1ubuntu1
> 2013-02-09 12:51:05 status installed man-db 2.6.0.2-2
> ```

**Output from `sudo apt-get install`**

> ```
> Reading package lists... Done
> Building dependency tree       
> Reading state information... Done
> You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>  steam:i386 : Depends: xterm:i386 but it is not installed or
>                        gnome-terminal:i386 but it is not installed
>               Depends: zenity:i386 but it is not installed
> E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f
> ```

Comment: Can you provide the list of some RECENT packages that you have installed?

Comment: @smartboyhw edit made.

Comment: actually this looks like the list of the recent repositories enabled instead of the latest packages you installed. Try run `cat /var/log/dpkg.log | grep "\ install\ ` and paste the output here.

Comment: @smartboyhw `cat /var/log/dpkg.log | grep "\ install\` just  gives me a prompt `>` because of the backslash  and no output without `\`

Comment: try `cat /var/log/dpkg.log | grep "\ install\ "` again....

Comment: @smartboyhw Edit made.

Comment: Just run `sudo apt-get install` and post the output. Delete the `cat /var/log/dpkg.log | grep "\ install\ " part:P

Comment: @smartboyhw Recent edit made.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

drN: The steam client is only supported in 12.04 or up, it is NOT supported in 11.10. So please remove the package steam by typing `sudo apt-get remove steam`.

Comment: Thanks! I'm glad one of us thought of that! `:P`

Comment: @drN if you can mark it as answer and upvote it:)

Comment: I'm just ridding my computer of the steam client. Once I have that done and perhaps restarted, I'll check for the error status and then mark it as an answer! `:)`

Comment: solved! Did not need a restart!