# apt-get install - - fix-broken killed everything

Tags: apt

Ubuntu 12.04

After an update, I got a red warning icon in the system tray saying something about dependency issues due to: Error: Broken Count > 0.

I googled it and found the following thread:

[Broken package after update: linux-headers, error broken count >0](https://askubuntu.com/questions/98752/broken-package-after-update-linux-headers-error-broken-count-0)

The guy there had the same issue and he could fix it using the command:

sudo apt-get install --fix-broken

So I did the same without thinking too much and the result was that seemingly every last program was removed from the system. Then I restarted my machine (quite stupid) and now I don't even get to the login screen.
Is there anything I can do besides reinstalling Ubuntu?

Comment: Have you tried to boot in "recovery mode"? You can access a terminal running in recovery mode?

Comment: Yes I can acces a terminal in this way.
But I don't really have a clue what to do then.

Answer (score 2):

As you can access a terminal, if you have internet access you can try to install the Ubuntu desktop:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

This should install all the default applications that are present in a fresh install. If that doesn't work you can use `dpkg` to get the list of the installed software and get the same list on a LiveCD, and install all the missing packages manually. To get the list use:

```
dpkg --get-selections > package_list.txt
```

Before trying anything, if you have important data there remember to use a LiveCD and **make a backup**!!!